# Kafka Streams with High Cardinality

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I currently have a Kafka Stream service:

```scala
{
    val _ = metrics
    val timeWindow = Duration.of(config.timeWindow.toMillis, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)
    val gracePeriod = Duration.of(config.gracePeriod.toMillis, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)

    val store = Materialized
      .as[AggregateKey, AggMetricDocument, ByteArrayWindowStore](
        config.storeNames.reducerStateStore
      )
      .withRetention(gracePeriod.plus(timeWindow))
      .withCachingEnabled()

    builder
      .stream[AggregateKey, AggMetricDocument(config.topicNames.aggMetricDocumentsIntermediate)
      .groupByKey
      .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(timeWindow).grace(gracePeriod))
      .reduce { (metricDoc1, metricDoc2) =>
        metricDoc1.copy(
          metrics = metricDoc1.metrics
            .merge(metricDoc2.metrics, config.metricDocumentsReducerSamplesReservoirSize),
          docsCount = metricDoc1.docsCount + metricDoc2.docsCount
        )
      }(store)
      .toStream
      .to(config.topicNames.aggMetricDocuments)(
        Produced.`with`(AggregateKey.windowedSerde, AggMetricDocument.flattenSerde)
      )
}
```

While

```scala
timeWindow=1m
gracePeriod=39h
```

The stream works fine on normal cardinality but when it starts processing high cardinality data(more than 100 million different keys) the processing rate declines after some time.

By looking at the RocksDB metrics it looks like the avg fetch latency is rising from 30µs to 600µs, and some decreasing in the hit rate of the filters and index as seen in the following test(sending ~15K/sec messages with uniqe keys):
[image]
[image]
[image]

The disk throughput and io seems under the disk limits.
The cpu usage and Load Avg increasing(the limit is 5 cores):

[image]
I made some RocksDB config modification:

```scala
private val cache = new LRUCache(2147483648, -1, false, 0.9) // 2GB
private val writeBufferManager = new WriteBufferManager(2147483648, cache)

val tableConfig = options.tableFormatConfig.asInstanceOf[BlockBasedTableConfig]
tableConfig.setBlockCache(BoundedMemoryRocksDBConfig.cache)
tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true) // Default false
tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocksWithHighPriority(true)
```

All other setting has the default values of Kafka Streams.
It seems that increasing the LRUCache helps for a while.

I am not sure what the core problem, Does someone have an idea of what causing this problem and which configuration should I tune to get better performance on high cardinality data.

Comment: How many partitions do you have?

Comment: @bbejeck 3 and I'm running with 3 threads

Comment: Did you find the cause for this?

Comment: I stop researching because it can be solved by just increasing the cache size(it delay the problem but that good for me).
The problem I think is that high cardinality caused a big amount of indexes and filters in the cache and when the cache is full RockesDB goes to the disk to see if the key exist there and that makes it much slower

It is a known issue in high DB/mem DB's as you can see here: https://rocksdb.org/blog/2017/05/12/partitioned-index-filter.html
but I guess high cardinality data has this problem as well